Кто знает как сделать на aiogram3.0 отправку эмодзи слота и получение его результата?
Нужно чтобы бот отправил эмодзи слота и получил результат

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Как то так:
@router.message(Command('slot'))
async def roll_dice(message: Message):
    data = await message.answer_dice(emoji='')
    await message.answer(f'Результат: {data.dice.value}')

при команде /slot бот отправляет эмодзи слота и выводит результат в чат
